# Node.js: Work with app.use & app.get together

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a react application rendering by my node server. I want in addition to rendering my react app, call my server as a API to recieve some data.

How is it possible to do it ?

Here my node server :

```
....

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/')), function(res, eq) {
});

app.get('/api/state', function (req, res) {
   ...
   res.end(state); // return a JSON
});
```

When I want to load data with axios, I can't access to the url '/api/state' from my client. Indeed my routes are handled by my client and the route 'api/state' doesn't exist.

I tried this solution :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/index');
});

app.use('/index', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/')), function(res, eq) {
});

app.get('/api/state', function (req, res) {
   ...
   res.end(state); // return a JSON
});
```

It works but my application reacts weirdly sometimes. 
Are there others solutions to do it ?

Thank's for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question entirely, but I think I understand your main concern.

Code from the client (including client routes, etc) will all be handled by React, via whatever you render in your static files.  I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "with my app.use I can't have access to the url '/api/state'.", but the basic pattern for this kind of app is to define all your JSON routes on the server as you've described and then use ajax requests from the client to fetch that data and render it in whatever clientside framework (react, angular, etc) that you want.

Often, you'll see folks define those data routes by prepending them with `/api` for clarity.

Your app.use should not have a callback as far as I know, you should just do

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/'));
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Indeed my question was not clearly explained. I edited my post. In fact I want to load data from my client with axios. However I can't call api/state from my client. What do you want to say by define all your JSON routes on the server as you've described ?? Declare the route api/state in my react router ?

Comment: I mean there's two sets of routes.  Your server will expose an API that delivers JSON data at certain endpoints (e.g. '/api/whatever').  Your client *should* then define user-facing routes that the browser will actually navigate to. Those user-facing routes will have code that calls the API to get whatever data is needed for the view.  I'm not sure why you say you can't call /api/state from your client.